# React-toastify :Addition of the colored theme in the toast options

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-toastify

I use `react-toastify` to display my toast, I created a component that allows me to display the toast according to the type.

```
import {
  Slide,
  toast
} from 'react-toastify';

const options = {
  autoClose: 5000,
  position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
  transition: Slide,
  closeOnClick: true,
  closeButton: false,
};

const Alert = (type: string, message: string) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'warning':
      return toast.warning(message);
    case 'error':
      return toast.error(message, options);
    case 'success':
      return toast.success(message);
    case 'info':
      return toast.info(message);
    case 'dark':
      return toast.dark(message);
    default:
      return toast(message);
  }
};

export default Alert;
```

And I call it like this:

```
Alert('error', 'Try Again');
```

`options` determine all the options I want to configure. But if I add in the options `theme: 'colored'`, I end up with the following message.

```
Argument of type '{ autoClose: number; position: ToastPosition; transition({ children, position, preventExitTransition, done, nodeRef, isIn }: ToastTransitionProps) => JSX.Element; closeOnClick: boolean; closeButton:boolean; theme: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ToastOptions<{}>'.

Types of property 'theme' are incompatible.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Theme | undefined'.
```

On the other hand if I make the call differently

```
case 'error':
  return toast.error(message, {
    theme: 'colored',
  });
```

I have no error message.

How to ensure that the theme is present in the options apply without error?

Comment: Hi, Did you get to solve it?

Comment: @MadhanS no, not yet

Comment: Are you using Typescript

Comment: yes i use Typescript

Comment: Then you should declare `theme` props in `ToastContainerProps` interface. I have added it in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare `theme` props in `ToastContainerProps` interface of `react-toastify` library, either in the root component or in `declaration.d.ts` file

```
declare module 'react-toastify' {
  export interface ToastContainerProps {
    theme?: string
  }
}
```